# How do stop updates in a sql server 2005 replication subscriber?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

I know I cannot make it read-only.
But is there an 'ordinary way' to do this?

If I deny everyone write, since deny is higher than grant, if will stop replication.

Jerry

Comment: Not sure what you are really asking. Some more details on why you want to do this?

Comment: I have a database on a server. I want to replicate that DB to another server.  That other DB has to be RW.  Users need to access it.  How do I give them Read Access with out doing more configuration everytime a new group is made?